# Can I set permissions to see one type of contribution, but not another?

Tags: civicontribute, permissions, acl

We have a number of staff who should have access to see event payment information, but who should not see donation information.  Is there a way to set permissions via ACL or otherwise based on Financial Type of the contribution?

Civi 4.6.6 -- soon to be 4.7; Drupal 7.41

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few years after the question was asked ... the answer is yes!

Financial ACL's were added a while back but the docs have not been updated yet.

- Go to `Administer > CiviContribute > CiviContribute Component Settings`, and tick `Enable Access Control by Financial Type`.
- Go to your CMS permissions to grant access to each financial type by role.

See [this blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/joe-murray/hiding-sensitive-contributions-from-some-staff) for details.